# Dart Console application error 'List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>' with enpoint

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this problem, I want to use an endpoint, but I have this error,
I just want to practice Dart, I'm new in this world of Dart :), I try to solve this with similar questions here, but I can't.

I have this problem:

**'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'**
This is a console application
this is my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:marchex_api/clases/business.dart';

void getMarchex(){

    final url = Uri.parse('https:#');
    http.get(url).then((res){
    final servicios =  Business.fromJson(res.body); 
    //print(servicios);
   }).catchError((error)=>print(error));

}
```

this is the class :

```
class Business {
    Business({
        required this.id,
        required this.businessName,
        required this.businessNumber,
        required this.billableDuration,
        required this.publisherPayout,
        required this.businessLatitude,
        required this.businessLongitude,
        required this.callTrackingNumber,
        required this.businessAddress1,
        required this.businessCity,
        required this.businessState,
        required this.businessZip,
        required this.postbackUrl,
        required this.businessShortDescription,
        required this.businessLongDescription,
    });

    String id;
    String businessName;
    String businessNumber;
    String billableDuration;
    String publisherPayout;
    String businessLatitude;
    String businessLongitude;
    String callTrackingNumber;
    String businessAddress1;
    String businessCity;
    String businessState;
    String businessZip;
    String postbackUrl;
    String businessShortDescription;
    String businessLongDescription;

   factory Business.fromJson(String str) => Business.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Business.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Business(
        id: json["id"],
        businessName: json["businessName"],
        businessNumber: json["businessNumber"] == null ? null : json["businessNumber"],
        billableDuration: json["billableDuration"],
        publisherPayout: json["publisherPayout"],
        businessLatitude: json["businessLatitude"] == null ? null : json["businessLatitude"],
        businessLongitude: json["businessLongitude"] == null ? null : json["businessLongitude"],
        callTrackingNumber: json["callTrackingNumber"],
        businessAddress1: json["businessAddress1"] == null ? null : json["businessAddress1"],
        businessCity: json["businessCity"] == null ? null : json["businessCity"],
        businessState: json["businessState"] == null ? null : json["businessState"],
        businessZip: json["businessZip"] == null ? null : json["businessZip"],
        postbackUrl: json["postbackUrl"],
        businessShortDescription: json["businessShortDescription"] == null ? null : json["businessShortDescription"],
        businessLongDescription: json["businessLongDescription"] == null ? null : json["businessLongDescription"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "businessName": businessName,
        "businessNumber": businessNumber == null ? null : businessNumber,
        "billableDuration": billableDuration,
        "publisherPayout": publisherPayout,
        "businessLatitude": businessLatitude == null ? null : businessLatitude,
        "businessLongitude": businessLongitude == null ? null : businessLongitude,
        "callTrackingNumber": callTrackingNumber,
        "businessAddress1": businessAddress1 == null ? null : businessAddress1,
        "businessCity": businessCity == null ? null : businessCity,
        "businessState": businessState == null ? null : businessState,
        "businessZip": businessZip == null ? null : businessZip,
        "postbackUrl": postbackUrl,
        "businessShortDescription": businessShortDescription == null ? null : businessShortDescription,
        "businessLongDescription": businessLongDescription == null ? null : businessLongDescription,
    };
}
```

Comment: Your API returns a list of business entries, so you'll want to end up with a `List<Business>`, yet in this line `final servicios =  Business.fromJson(res.body)` you are trying to parse the whole list as a single business.

Answer (score 1):

Your API returns a list of business entries, so you'll want to end up with a `List<Business>`, yet in this line `final servicios =  Business.fromJson(res.body)` you are trying to parse the whole list as a single business. Loop over the decoded `List<dynamic>` to parse each element to a business as follows:

```
  final url = Uri.parse(
    'https://services.marchex.com/mcm/listings?partnerId=bchybs0z&searchType=keywordOrBusiness&searchTerm=Attorney&zip=30334&limit=20&radius=40',
  );
  final response = await http.get(url);

  final j = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;

  final businesses = j
      .map<Business>((e) => Business.fromMap(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList();
```

BTW, the code of your named constructor is overly complicated and probably wrong. You are testing for null and then trying to assign null to a `String` rather than a `String?`. Prefer to use the `??` operator and supply dummy values if using `String` vs `String?`:

```
class Business {
  Business({
    required this.id,
    required this.businessName,
    required this.businessNumber,
    required this.billableDuration,
    required this.publisherPayout,
    required this.businessLatitude,
    required this.businessLongitude,
    required this.callTrackingNumber,
    required this.businessAddress1,
    required this.businessCity,
    required this.businessState,
    required this.businessZip,
    required this.postbackUrl,
    required this.businessShortDescription,
    required this.businessLongDescription,
  });

  String id;
  String businessName;
  String businessNumber;
  String billableDuration;
  String publisherPayout;
  String businessLatitude;
  String businessLongitude;
  String callTrackingNumber;
  String businessAddress1;
  String businessCity;
  String businessState;
  String businessZip;
  String postbackUrl;
  String businessShortDescription;
  String businessLongDescription;

  factory Business.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Business(
        id: json['id'],
        businessName: json['businessName'],
        businessNumber: json['businessNumber'] ?? '',
        billableDuration: json['billableDuration'],
        publisherPayout: json['publisherPayout'],
        businessLatitude: json['businessLatitude'] ?? '',
        businessLongitude: json['businessLongitude'] ?? '',
        callTrackingNumber: json['callTrackingNumber'],
        businessAddress1: json['businessAddress1'] ?? '',
        businessCity: json['businessCity'] ?? '',
        businessState: json['businessState'] ?? '',
        businessZip: json['businessZip'] ?? '',
        postbackUrl: json['postbackUrl'],
        businessShortDescription: json['businessShortDescription'] ?? '',
        businessLongDescription: json['businessLongDescription'] ?? '',
      );
}
```